# fastlane getting CommandPhaseScript execution error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, fastlane

Hey guys is my first time when I use fastlane and after I've managed to configure fastlane successfully I ran 'fastlane beta' in my iOS folder and got into this error after 10 minutes of processing

```
▸ Processing Info.plist
▸ Running script 'Bundle React Native code and images'
    the transform cache was reset.
▸ Generating 'Vert.app.dSYM'
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/mariushincu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vert-dumzflwpkmrgprcgqfpxkqvpyyyw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Vert/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Vert.build/Release-iphoneos/Vert.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'Vert' from project 'Vert')
(1 failure)
[11:03:05]: Exit status: 65

+-------------+-------------------------------------+
|                 Build environment                 |
+-------------+-------------------------------------+
| xcode_path  | /Volumes/Work/Applications/Xcode.a  |
|             | pp                                  |
| gym_version | 2.199.0                             |
| sdk         | iPhoneOS15.0.sdk                    |
+-------------+-------------------------------------+

[11:03:05]: ▸ Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
[11:03:05]: ▸ GenerateDSYMFile /Users/mariushincu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vert-dumzflwpkmrgprcgqfpxkqvpyyyw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Vert/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Vert.app.dSYM /Users/mariushincu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vert-dumzflwpkmrgprcgqfpxkqvpyyyw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Vert/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Vert.app/Vert (in target 'Vert' from project 'Vert')
[11:03:05]: ▸     cd /Volumes/Work/Desktop/workspace_es/development-rider/ios
[11:03:05]: ▸     /Volumes/Work/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/mariushincu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vert-dumzflwpkmrgprcgqfpxkqvpyyyw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Vert/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Vert.app/Vert -o /Users/mariushincu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vert-dumzflwpkmrgprcgqfpxkqvpyyyw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Vert/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Vert.app.dSYM
[11:03:05]: 
[11:03:05]: ⬆️  Check out the few lines of raw `xcodebuild` output above for potential hints on how to solve this error
[11:03:05]:   For the complete and more detailed error log, check the full log at:
[11:03:05]:   /Users/mariushincu/Library/Logs/gym/Vert-Vert.log
[11:03:05]: 
[11:03:05]: Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
[11:03:05]: It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
[11:03:05]: to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
[11:03:05]: Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
[11:03:05]: sure your project is set up correctly.
[11:03:05]: fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
[11:03:05]: the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
[11:03:05]: Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
[11:03:05]: 
+------------------+----------+
|        Lane Context         |
+------------------+----------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | ios      |
| PLATFORM_NAME    | ios      |
| LANE_NAME        | ios beta |
| BUILD_NUMBER     | 28       |
+------------------+----------+
[11:03:05]: Error building the application - see the log above

+------+------------------------+-------------+
|              fastlane summary               |
+------+------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                 | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform       | 0           |
| 2    | increment_build_numbe  | 2           |
|      | r                      |             |
|    | build_app              | 743         |
+------+------------------------+-------------+

[11:03:05]: fastlane finished with errors
```

This is what I found on the end of the actual log in Vert-Vert.log file

```
    node --max-old-space-size=8192 /volumes/work/desktop/workspace_es/development-rider/node_modules/react-native/cli.js bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --reset-cache --bundle-output /Users/mariushincu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vert-dumzflwpkmrgprcgqfpxkqvpyyyw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Vert/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/main.jsbundle --assets-dest /Users/mariushincu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vert-dumzflwpkmrgprcgqfpxkqvpyyyw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Vert/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Vert.app --minify false
warning: the transform cache was reset.
                    Welcome to Metro!
              Fast - Scalable - Integrated


error SHA-1 for file /volumes/work/desktop/workspace_es/development-rider/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/assets/empty-module.js (/volumes/work/desktop/workspace_es/development-rider/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/assets/empty-module.js) is not computed.
         Potential causes:
           1) You have symlinks in your project - watchman does not follow symlinks.
           2) Check `blockList` in your metro.config.js and make sure it isn't excluding the file path.
ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file /volumes/work/desktop/workspace_es/development-rider/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/assets/empty-module.js (/volumes/work/desktop/workspace_es/development-rider/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/assets/empty-module.js) is not computed.
         Potential causes:
           1) You have symlinks in your project - watchman does not follow symlinks.
           2) Check `blockList` in your metro.config.js and make sure it isn't excluding the file path.
    at DependencyGraph.getSha1 (/volumes/work/desktop/workspace_es/development-rider/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:245:13)
    at Transformer.transformFile (/volumes/work/desktop/workspace_es/development-rider/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:104:23)
    at Bundler.transformFile (/volumes/work/desktop/workspace_es/development-rider/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:48:30)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
    at async Object.transform (/volumes/work/desktop/workspace_es/development-rider/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:101:12)
    at async processModule (/volumes/work/desktop/workspace_es/development-rider/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:137:18)
    at async addDependency (/volumes/work/desktop/workspace_es/development-rider/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:230:18)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async processModule (/volumes/work/desktop/workspace_es/development-rider/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:198:5)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

GenerateDSYMFile /Users/mariushincu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vert-dumzflwpkmrgprcgqfpxkqvpyyyw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Vert/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Vert.app.dSYM /Users/mariushincu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vert-dumzflwpkmrgprcgqfpxkqvpyyyw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Vert/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Vert.app/Vert (in target 'Vert' from project 'Vert')
    cd /Volumes/Work/Desktop/workspace_es/development-rider/ios
    /Volumes/Work/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/mariushincu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vert-dumzflwpkmrgprcgqfpxkqvpyyyw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Vert/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Vert.app/Vert -o /Users/mariushincu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vert-dumzflwpkmrgprcgqfpxkqvpyyyw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Vert/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Vert.app.dSYM
```

I want to mention that I've tried to make the archive from Xcode after this error and it finished it successfully without any error.

Can anyone explain to me what should be the reason?

Comment: did you clean derived data before running the lane?

Comment: @IvanGeorgiev I've cleaned derived data, device support, archives, removed node_modules, pods and reinstalled again and same thing. For some reason I can see that it has something to do with metro but I don't get that thing. Is a react-native app

Comment: There are two potential causes in the error log, are you able to confirm that these are not the cause? 1) You have symlinks in your project 2) heck `blockList` in your metro.config.js and make sure it isn't excluding the file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this problem by creating a fastlane folder in the root folder of my react-native project and inside that I have initiated the fastlane command. Before I used to have the fastlane folder inside iOS folder.

Now the folder structure looks like this

- Root

  - android
  - ios
  - fastlane

    - Appfile
    - Fastfile
    - Gemfile
    - Gymfile